# Asymptotic estimate for an expression of

Tags: asymptotics

\begin{equation}
A = \frac{(\frac12-\frac{1}{n})(\frac12-\frac{2}{n})...(\frac12-\frac{t-1}{n})}{(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n})(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{n})... (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{n})}
\end{equation}

Can we get an asymptotic estimate for above A? Assume $n \gg 1$ and $t \ll n$

Comment: Do you have one more term in the denominator?

Comment: No. I checked it.

Comment: Multiply with $\dfrac{(2n)^t}{(2n)^t}$ .